# Timed out message receiving from renderer: 0.100 log messages using ChromeDriver and Chrome v80 through Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver, timeout

I recently updated my chrome from v74 to v80. Now I am facing timeout messaging rending when I run my script which was running successfully on v74.

My code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/sharukh/Downloads/chromedriver1/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
driver.get("https://www.mariatash.com/");
```

Help me out on this issue.

Comment: did you update your chrome ?

Comment: yes, updated chrome from v74 to v80

Comment: Did you update the chromedriver? You should have ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106.

Comment: yes. but still getting runtime

Comment: the script is running but getting runtime error.

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}) on port 32011
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Feb 26, 2020 7:58:21 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1582727303.883][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1582727303.985][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); try this and see whts the behavior

Comment: @SSufiyaan are you able to run your code successfully or browser just opens up blank ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver

Comment: Can I downgrade the chrome + chrome driver?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver

This is a known-issue, it's not actually a failure but a retry attempt to listen to chrome.  The severity tag confuses the user, and there is a fix on the way. You could also down grade to version 79 and it works with chrome 80.

[image]

If you want to surpress this message temporarily for now then,

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true"); //THIS will surpress all logs expect INFO


    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF); // this could be used to stop INFO logging in chrome driver
```

[image]

Comment: Can I downgrade the chrome + chromedriver?

Comment: @SSufiyaan ya but you don't have to it's just a polling message

Comment: but it looks bad when scripts are running...

Comment: @SSufiyaan use the mentioned method if you want to supress it , else downgrade chromedriver n chrome if you don't have requirement to test in chrome 80

Comment: This no longer works with Chrome 81 as ChromeDriver 79 will not support 81

Comment: @KeithTyler the mentioned answer works with 81

Comment: @PDHide You can't use Chromedriver 79 with Chrome 81 or above. It will reject it with an incompatibility error.

Comment: "A fix is on the way" I don't know why it's taking this long to remove an errant error message. This post was in February, it's now April.

Answer (score 1):

You can also suppress error message using ChromeDriverService class:

```
    WebDriver browser = null;

    ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:\\chromedriver.exe")).usingPort(4444).withSilent(true)
            .build();
        service.start();



        browser = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), new ChromeOptions());
```

and once the test is over stop the service , else the port remains opened.

```
browser.quit()
service.stop()
```

Comment: can I downgrade the chrome + driver?

Answer (score 0):

Add this after you initialize the browser. It worked for me.

System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");